# Using the NOAA API Token to pull in data

Tags: r, noaa, rnoaa

I am trying to pull weather data from NOAA's API
I've downloaded rnoaa, httrm and jsonlite packages.

I want to run this piece of code

```
ncdc_stations(datasetid='GHCND', locationid='FIPS:12017', stationid='GHCND:USC00084289')
```

I get the error message:

Error in getOption("noaakey", stop("need an API key for NOAA data")) : 
  need an API key for NOAA data

I have a token, how do I implement it into the code?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe reading [this](https://grantwinney.com/day-7-noaa-api/) can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO! I'm unfamiliar with the library but it sounds like you need to add `token =  "YOUR_TOKEN"` into each function call, eg:

```
libary(rnoaa)
ncdc(datasetid = 'PRECIP_HLY', locationid = 'ZIP:28801',
     datatypeid = 'HPCP', limit = 5, token =  "YOUR_TOKEN")
```

or alternatively (and sounds much easier rather than including that argument for each `rnoaa`function call), just use `options(noaakey = "KEY_EMAILED_TO_YOU")` once at the top of your script.

taken from:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rnoaa/versions/0.9.5